# E4 make perspective appear in System perspectives list

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have a perspective that is defined in the model fragment (e4xmi) and when opening it from the Window->Open perspective it appears in the User-Defined perspectives list. How can I make it appear in the System perspectives list ? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean be 'User Defined' and 'System' perspectives list?

Comment: @greg-449 : by "user-defined" list i mean the perspectives that were added with a "Save As" option. The system perspectives are the default ones. Interesting to note that if I define my perspective in the plugin.xml "Extensions" tab as well, then it appears under the System perspectives list.

Comment: @greg-449 : Do you have any idea why would a perspective defined in the model fragment only be considered as if it was built using the "Save As.." eclipse command.

Comment: I stll don't understand what you mean by 'System perspectives list'. What list is this?

Comment: @greg-449: They are the perspectives we defined, in their default state. If a user opens a perspective and makes some changes in it, he can then right click->save as.. and the perspective will be added to the user-defined list.

Comment: @greg-449: so the problem is that the perspective i contribute via the model fragment appears in the defined perpspective list from the start, while if I also define it in the plugin.xml it does not.